# Android jet pack architecture component navigation is not working in java?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack

I have a problem in android jet pack navigation in java. Using this, when i go from one fragment to another the previous fragment was destroyed but i want to save the previous fragment history. In kotlin it is working fine.

For example, I have a three fragment in which every fragment has an edit text. when i enter text in fragment 1 and go to next fragment 2 then fragment 1 is destroying.When i go to back from fragment 2 fragment 1 is recreating . fragment pause and resume state is not working by using this architecture.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        FrameLayout sectionHomeWrapper;


        NavController navHomeController;
        Fragment navHomeFragment;


        NavController currentController = null;


        BottomNavigationView navigation = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            sectionHomeWrapper=findViewById(R.id.section_home_wrapper);


            navHomeController= Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.section_home);

          navigation=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
            currentController = navHomeController;
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigation, currentController);


            sectionHomeWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

    }
```

main activity layout file in which navHost is adding
activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/section_home_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/section_home"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="false"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_section_home"
            />
    </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation graph file in which navigation is linking.
nav_graph_section_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.dps.navigation.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_notificationFragment_to_detailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.dps.navigation.DetailFragment"
        android:label="HomeDetailFragment">

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.dps.navigation.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="DashboardFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_notificationFragment_to_detailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.dps.navigation.NotificationFragment"
        android:label="DashboardFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_notificationFragment_to_detailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.dps.navigation.DetailFragment"
        android:label="DetailFragment"/>
</navigation>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPFQk.png)

Comment: Can you post the code of next button from your fragment please?

Comment: sure..


 navController=Navigation.findNavController(view);
navController.navigate(R.id.next_action, args);

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
navController=Navigation.findNavController(view);
navController.navigate(R.id.next_action, args);
```

Write this in your button:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.your_action);
```

Please comment if any issues.

Comment: i think you don't under stand what i am saying.
I have a three fragment in which every fragment has an edit text.
when i enter text in fragment 1 and go to next fragment 2 then fragment 1 is destroying because on back pressed from fragment 2 fragment 1 is recreating .

Comment: Oh, Sorry, are you clicking the button to go to next fragment? @Ahtisham

Comment: no not working.....you can do download code from below link:-\n https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkUkZ7QpuzZ7k8xoXXZaXN5YMzNHdw